# When div content finished loading, How do I remove the placeholder?

Tags: jquery, css, placeholder

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/placeholder-loading/dist/css/placeholder-loading.min.css">
<div class="ph-item">
    <div class="ph-col-12">
        <div class="ph-picture"></div>
        <div class="ph-row">
            <div class="ph-col-6 big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-4 empty big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-2 big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-4"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-8 empty"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-6"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-6 empty"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code. I am using Placeholder loding css. After Div Content loaded How do I remove placeholder loader.

Comment: Where is the `div` content is loaded? If you no need to use `<div class="ph-item">` anymore, you would use `jQuery` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to implement this as a place holder for content that is not yet there, e.g Ajax calls, rendering objects (for other frameworks like React, Vue.js ... etc), for jQuery you can have this removed on page load, or maybe using `ajax.done()` method and so on.

the following might be a starting point for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.ph-item').replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2><div>Content is ready!</div>" );
  }, 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/placeholder-loading/dist/css/placeholder-loading.min.css">
<div class="ph-item">
    <div class="ph-col-12">
        <div class="ph-picture"></div>
        <div class="ph-row">
            <div class="ph-col-6 big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-4 empty big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-2 big"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-4"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-8 empty"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-6"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-6 empty"></div>
            <div class="ph-col-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!. Could you please tell me what is the best way to use Placeholder CSS

Comment: you are welcome! but what do you want to know, not sure what you mean.